# iphone center text in cell of table

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, center

hi guys [I think this is rather basic, but cannot find how to do it!]

how can I center the text in the cells of my table view?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It used to be UITextAlignmentCenter

From iOS6 it is NSTextAlignmentCenter.

Have a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467288/center-align-text-in-uitableviewcell-problem) and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12793054/253169)

Comment: hi Thanks a lot!, that did it, I had to change my StyleSubtitle to initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault,, now working Cheers!