# What are good alternatives to UITextAlignmentCenter in iOS 6?

Tags: ios6

`UITextAlignmentCenter` seems to be deprecated in iOS 6. What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

For IOS 6 you should use `NSTextAlignmentCenter` instead of `UITextAlignmentCenter`:

```
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604632/how-do-you-add-multi-line-text-to-a-uibutton/12776945#12776945)

And if you want backward compatibiliy to IOS 5 also you can do this,

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
# define ALIGN_CENTER NSTextAlignmentCenter
#else
# define ALIGN_CENTER UITextAlignmentCenter
#endif
```

Answer (score 9):

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
# define ALIGN_CENTER NSTextAlignmentCenter
#else
# define ALIGN_CENTER UITextAlignmentCenter
#endif

UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
label.text = @"There is no spoon";
label.textAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER;
[self addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```
newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

instead of

```
newLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `NSTextAlignmentCenter` instead according to Apple's documentation.

You should also use `NSTextAlignmentLeft` and `NSTextAlignmentRight` instead of `UITextAlignmentLeft` and `UITextAlignmentRight`, respectively.

Comment: You have a typo. It's: `NSTextAlignmentCenter`

Answer (score 3):

In Swift: `NSTextAlignment.center`