# SWRevealViewController right side menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am experimenting inserting a UITableView into the RightViewController of the first example located at https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/tree/master/RevealControllerExample .

The issue is that that the table is aligned far left and the text in each cell is cutoff.

What are possible fixes for this? I have looked through the SWRevealViewController api and could not find a solution. Also, i looked through the UITableView api and tried each of the possible alignment setting, also in the xib builder. None seems to change the cutoff of the text

I have attached the image below. Notice the left aligned table.

[image: right side controller]
<sub>(source: [jeffcoat.net](http://www.jeffcoat.net/rightsidecontroller.png))</sub>

Comment: Hi can you take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517100/swrevealviewcontroller-rightviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of
[Center Align text in UITableViewCell problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467288/center-align-text-in-uitableviewcell-problem)
modified for right instead of center I was able to get the menu to align to the right and final code is below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

if (nil == cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
}


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi.. I have seen your active participation in SWRevealViewController.i got issue While using SWRevealViewController.can you go through once this url.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987486/app-login-issue-using-swrevealviewcontroller . Please guide me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 12):

assign 0 to _rightViewRevealOverdraw  property of SWRevealViewController using below line

self.revealViewController.rightViewRevealOverdraw = 0.0f;

Or

in `SWRevealViewController.m` file search for line

```
_rightViewRevealOverdraw = 60.0f;
```

and change it like

```
_rightViewRevealOverdraw = 0.0f;
```

This will fix your problem.

More improved solution is to write below single line in controller instead of library.

```
  self.revealViewController.rightViewRevealOverdraw = 0.0f;
```

Comment: This seemed to work at the moment. Although I am a little worried about what those values currently do and how they affect the view.

Answer (score 8):

> In SWRevealViewController.m file search for line
>   _rightViewRevealOverdraw = 60.0f; and change it like _rightViewRevealOverdraw = 0.0f;

Amit Saxenas answer above helped me, but instead of modifying the SWRevealViewController.m, the header file for the class declares a public property that can be set to change the rightViewRevealOverdraw.

```
self.revealViewController.rightViewRevealOverdraw = 0.0f;
[self.revealButtonItem setTarget:self.revealViewController];
[self.revealButtonItem setAction:@selector( rightRevealToggle: )];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the default `_rightViewRevealOverdraw` is `60.0f`, you could use AutoLayout to make the tableView snap to all edges of your ViewController except for a `Leading Space Margin` of `60`.

This would effectively give the tableView a frame of `(60.0, 0, view.frame.size.width - 60.0, view.frame.size.height)`, allowing it to span across only the visible area.