# App login issue using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

My App having sideMenu like facebook so i can implement that using `SWRevealViewController` (Storyboards)library.It was working fine.I got one issue.

Let me explain my situation.

My app has a login view. If the login informations are ok then i can saved the user information in `NSUserdefaults`.From next time onwards the user directly moves to `HomeViewController`(not login required).My `homeviewController` is `TabbarController`.I can implement this using storyboards(SWRevealViewController).I'm stuck here .So can one give me some guidance how to implement this? I'm new to storyboards

In Appdelegate.m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
       if ([defaults valueForKey:@"USERID"]) {

        SidebarViewController *rearViewController = [[SidebarViewController alloc] init];

        RootTabViewController *frontViewController = [[RootTabViewController alloc] init];

        SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController =
                                        [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:rearViewController frontViewController:frontViewController];

           self.window.rootViewController = mainRevealController;

        }
        return YES;

}
```

This is my storyboard:

Comment: u have checked the defaults value is come or not

Comment: if u r using storyboard call the this method  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102978/swrevealviewcontroller-without-using-navigationcontroller/23105142#23105142 else ..

Comment: Hi anbu..I have checked default value it coming..my problem How to directly move to homeViewController if user login using SWRevealViewController

Comment: r u using story board

Comment: Yes.Anbu.im using Storyboards