# Make right button visible in a slide out panel with a navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I currently have a view with a navigation controller and two menu bar items, the left one causes a slide out panel to appear using SWReveal. What I want to do is add a navigation controller to the slide out panel, but make it so the right button doesn't get cut off by the upper view.[image: This is what I have.]

I want a button just to the left of where the hamburger button on the upper view is. I'd like to do this in Swift, if there's no way to do it in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843773/swrevealviewcontroller-right-side-menu). Just go into `SWRevealViewController.m`, scroll down to the `_initDefaultProperties` block, and change the value of `_rearViewRevealOverdraw` from `60.0f` to `0.0f`.